# Use-as-you-wish AI-generated portraits of human faces

Tags: gratis, web-development, photography, pixel-graphics

Are there any comprehensive collections of AI-generated portraits of human faces (*photorealistic*, male/female, old/young, different skin colors, various facial expressions) that are *free to use*?

Analogous to the free Icon Sets (such as fontawesome.com), but more a "faces set". Free to use just as with photos from, say, unsplash.com.

I sometimes have to build mockups of web pages, for demo or development purposes. Often these pages have a portrait photo inside, or an avatar picture.

I wonder if there are collections of AI-generated faces such as this spectacular [collection of  superhero characters](https://twitter.com/Siberian_644/status/1432349414941773830) - but these images look unnatural and are certainly not free to use.

For more natural looking faces take a look at [thispersondoesnotexist.com](https://thispersondoesnotexist.com/) , or just perform a web search for ["GAN AI faces"](https://www.google.com/search?q=GAN+AI+faces). Or check out this [github repo of GAN code](https://github.com/NVlabs/stylegan2).

Comment: Why does it need to be AI generated?

Comment: To avoid issues with data protection,  personality rights, later complaints of real persons who want their pictures removed.

Answer (score 1):

Note to self: Such faces will be already available on [Microsoft's website:  *Fake It Till You Make It: Face analysis in the wild using synthetic data alone*.](https://microsoft.github.io/FaceSynthetics/)

Microsoft Researchers  intend to release their big dataset:

> Our dataset of 100,000 synthetic faces with 2D landmark and per-pixel segmentation labels will be available to download soon, for non-commercial research purposes. Please watch this space.

Comment: The dataset is available now, but its license terms do not seem to allow for your use case, as it has been made "available for non-commercial research purposes" only.